# Improve a haskell script

Tags: haskell, coding-style

I'm a newbie in Haskell and I'd like some opinions about improving this script. This is a code generator and requires a command line argument to generate the sql script.

```
./GenCode "people name:string age:integer"
```

Code:

```
import Data.List
import System.Environment (getArgs)

create_table :: String -> String

create_table str =  "CREATE TABLE " ++ h (words str)
        where h (x:xs) = let cab = x
                             final = xs
                         in x ++ "( " ++ create_fields xs ++ ")"

create_fields (x:xs) = takeWhile (/=':') x ++ type x ++ sig
              where sig | length xs > 0 = "," ++ create_fields xs
                        | otherwise     = " " ++ create_fields xs
create_fields []     = ""

type x | isInfixOf "string"  x = " CHARACTER VARYING"
       | isInfixOf "integer" x = " INTEGER"
       | isInfixOf "date"    x = " DATE"
       | isInfixOf "serial"  x = " SERIAL"
       | otherwise             = ""

main = mainWith 
  where mainWith = do
      args <- getArgs
  case args of
       [] -> putStrLn $ "You need one argument"
       (x:xs) -> putStrLn $ (create_table x)
```

Comment: `_` is usually used for ignored parameters, and there's no need to use `f $ g` and `f (g)` together (`$` has lower precedence than function application), e.g. `(x:_) -> putStrLn $ create_table x`.

Comment: a lot of suggestions here you would also get from hlint. it's pretty great, check it out: http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/

Comment: `type` is not a good name for a Haskell function as it's a reserved word. Use e.g. `type_' instead. Also, put in type signatures for all the top-level functions. 'case args...' needs to be indented to line up with 'args' on the line above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you understand how to write functional code already. Here are some small style notes:

- Haskell usually uses camelCase, not under_score_separation
- In `create_table`, `cabo` and `final` are not used.
- Usually a list-recursive function like create_fields puts the empty list case first.
- I would not make create_fields recursive anyway. The comma-joining code is quite complicated and should be separated from the typing code. Instead do something like `Data.List.intercalate "," (map create_field xs)`. Then `create_field x` can just be `takeWhile (/=':') x ++ type x`
- Especially if there are a lot of types to be translated, you might put them into a map

Like so:

```
types = Data.Map.fromList [("string", "CHARACTER VARYING")
                          ,("integer", "INTEGER")
                          -- etc
                          ]
```

Then `type` can be `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe "" (Data.Map.lookup x types)`

- Code can appear in any order, so it's nice to have `main` up front. (This is personal preference though)
- You don't need mainWith.

Just say

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [] -> ...
```

- You don't need the dollar for the calls to `putStrLn`. In the first call, the argument wouldn't require parentheses anyway, and in the second, you supply the parentheses. Alternatively, you could keep the second dollar and drop the parentheses.

Comment: I don't think that the camelCase style that is used for haskell library functions is relevant as a style guide for personal code, unless that code is going to be published. Otherwise, good points.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `length xs > 0` (in `sig`); it needlessly counts the length of `xs` when all you really wanted to know is whether it's empty.  Use `null xs` to check for a non-empty list:

```
...
where sig | null xs   = ... -- Empty case
          | otherwise = ... -- Non-empty case
```

or add an argument to `sig` and pattern match:

```
...
where sig (y:ys) = ...
      sig []     = ...
```

Although Nathan Sanders' advice to replace the whole recursive thing with `intercalate` is excellent and makes this a moot point.

---

You're also identifying the type by passing the whole `"var:type"` string into `type`, so it is testing

```
"string" `isInfixOf` "name:string"
```

etc.

You could use `break` or `span` instead of `takeWhile` to separate the name and type earlier:

```
create_fields (x:xs) = xname ++ type xtype ++ sig
    where
      (xname, _:xtype) = break (==':') x
      sig = ...
```

and then `type` can compare for string equality, or look up values using a `Map`.

A quick explanation of that use of `break`:

```
break (==':') "name:string" == ("name", ":string")
```

Then when binding

```
(xname, _:xtype) to ("name", ":string"),

 xname -> "name"
 _     -> ':'      (discarded)
 xtype -> "string"
```